# Trigger API Gateway Lambda as webhook URL from AWS Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-pinpoint

I want to trigger API FGateway Lambda as custom URL from AWS Pinpoint, but getting nest error

> Bad request: The data we received didn't match the format we expected for the updateJourney operation. Confirm that the information in your request is formatted properly, and then submit your request again.
> Details
> Request Id dd470a0c: Activity validation failed: Amazon Pinpoint received an **invalid response from the resource at the specified URL**. Verify that you specified the correct URL.

[image]

Looks like API Gateway should return a specific response but I can not find docs related to it.
Would appriciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Unser is next:

1. We need to have HEAD method with a X-Amz-Pinpoint-AccountId = aws account id header in response
2. AWS will send data to POST method